# ubuntu and unity randomly unresponsive

Tags: unity, graphics

Some times randomly, ubuntu 14.04 gets unity super slow and unresponsive, and when using the browser i get the screen pretty chopped when scrolling down. (like in the image)[image]

ubuntu in general gets pretty slow and very unresponsive, the only way to fix it is restarting several times.

also i notice is on this "breaking mode" when unity bar change color not from the desktop picture, but a purple color.

I'm using Intel Atom CPU D525 @ 1.80GHz × 4, Intel IGD x86/MMX/SSE2

what can be the issue?

Comment: What GPU hardware / driver are you using?